# SSH line-by-line mode?

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there ([RFC1184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1184)-alike) line-by-line mode for OpenSSH?

In the olden days, before SSH, there was telnet.

Telnet had two modes of operation: one like SSH (char-by-char mode, where each key pressed would be immediately sent to other side) and another one called "line mode" (line-by-line), where you would input whole line (and edit it if needed) and only when you pressed enter, whole line would be sent over network (usually in single TCP packet).

While char-by-char mode was generally more convenient, line-mode was extremely useful on high-latency (and/or high packet loss) links.

It however seems to be missing from OpenSSH client. Does anybody knows of other FOSS SSH implementations or openssh patches or other clever tricks which might provide something similar? What I'm *not* interested in is:

- non-free software (closed source ssh client looks like it has it)
- telnetd/SSL instead of SSH (server side must remain SSH2 compatible as there are lots of other users)
- other packet-loss mitigation techniques (like tcp_westwood etc).

Any ideas?